# Find XPATH with namespace and based on parent element

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have the following xml:

```
...
    <chapter>
        <start_time>00:01:04</start_time>
    </chapter>  
    <chapter>
        <start_time>00:01:05</start_time>
    </chapter>  
...
```

Currently, to get the start_times I am doing:

```
start_times = node.xpath("//t:start_time/text()", 
                   namespaces={'t':'http://example.com/namespace'})
```

However, I am also getting `start_times` from non-chapter elements:

```
[00:00:01, 00:00:02, 00:01:04, 00:01:05]
```

In addition, for some reason suing `//t:chapter/start_time` returns an empty result.

How would I get only those `start_times` that have a parent element of `chapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your selector more specific like this:

```
start_times = node.xpath("//t:chapter/start_time/text()", 
                   namespaces={'t':'http://example.com/namespace'})
```

Comment: For some reason, using `//t:start_time` works, but using `//t:chapter/start_time` does not work. I'm not sure why, but this may be related to the namespace.

Comment: try adding the namespace to start_time as well: //t:chapter/t:start_time

Comment: Yea, explicitly defining the namespace on every element.